# Python requests base64 image

Tags: python, base64, python-requests, data-uri

I am using `requests` to get the image from remote URL. Since the images will always be 16x16, I want to convert them to `base64`, so that I can embed them later to use in HTML `img` tag.

```
import requests
import base64
response = requests.get(url).content
print(response)
b = base64.b64encode(response)
src = "data:image/png;base64," + b
```

The output for `response` is:

```
response = b'GIF89a\x80\x00\x80\x00\xc4\x1f\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\xff\x00\x00\xff\x88\x88"""\xffff\...
```

The HTML part is:

```
<img src="{{src}}"/>
```

But the image is not displayed.

How can I properly base-64 encode the `response`?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think it's "I have a `str` with (with image data in it, but that doesn't really mater). How can I base-64 encode it so I can build a data URI from it?"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think it's just

```
import base64
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
uri = ("data:" + 
       response.headers['Content-Type'] + ";" +
       "base64," + base64.b64encode(response.content))
```

Assuming `content-type` is set.

Comment: This works as  expected! I only needed to change `base64.b64encode(response.content))` to `str(base64.b64encode(r.content).decode("utf-8")))`. Thank you!

Comment: I'm really surprised you had to do that, but the types you get back from functions like `b64encode()` and the types urllib takes can surprise you. Also, is this Python 3?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
import base64
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
uri = ("data:" + 
       response.headers['Content-Type'] + ";" +
       "base64," + base64.b64encode(response.content).decode("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use the base64 package.

```
import requests
import base64

response = requests.get(url).content
print(response)
b64response = base64.b64encode(response)
print b64response
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code to send/receive images over Http requests, encoded with base64

> Send Request:

```
# Read Image
image_data = cv2.imread(image_path)
# Convert numpy array To PIL image
pil_detection_img = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img_detections, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

# Convert PIL image to bytes
buffered_detection = BytesIO()

# Save Buffered Bytes
pil_detection_img.save(buffered_detection, format='PNG')

# Base 64 encode bytes data
# result : bytes
base64_detection = base64.b64encode(buffered_detection.getvalue())

# Decode this bytes to text
# result : string (utf-8)
base64_detection = base64_detection.decode('utf-8')
base64_plate = base64_plate.decode('utf-8')

data = {
    "cam_id": "10415",
    "detecion_image": base64_detection,
}
```

> Recieve Request

```
content = request.json
encoded_image = content['image']
decoded_image = base64.b64decode(encoded_image)

out_image = open('image_name', 'wb')
out_image.write(decoded_image)
```