# Sending image from flask to javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

I am trying to send an image from the flask server to the web script. The first server connects to another API and gets an image. I don't want to save this image just forward it to the web application script.

```py
@app.route('/api/image', methods=['GET'])
def return_image():
    r = requests.get(f"{api_url}/image")
    return send_file(
    BytesIO(r.content),
    mimetype='image/jpeg',
    as_attachment=True,
    attachment_filename='test.jpg')
```

I am trying to get this image by ajax request and display it.

```
function updateImage() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/image",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'image/jpg',
    success: function (res) {
      $(theImg).attr("src", 'data:image/png;base64,'+ res);
      M.toast({
        html: 'Loading image: Success'
      })
    },
    error: function () {
      M.toast({
        html: 'Loading image: Fail'
      })
    }
  });
}
```

I tried to make this work but wasn't able to. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance your JS writes a data-uri to the src attribute, but `res` is actually the binary data with a `image/png` mimetype.

So you either need to base64 encode `r.content` on the server side, [here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30280565/2052575) which actually creates the entire uri server side, then return that string and have your JS add that to the `src` attribute.

Or if you just want make your JS support the exisitng endpoint you could probably [create a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52410044/2052575) based on `/api/image` response, then [write that to the img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51756149/2052575).